# Vue / Vuetify - this.$refs.form.reset() error in file input

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I was using `this.$refs.form.reset()` for my modal and all the fields are cleared not until I used the `v-file-input` field. The error produces `Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.`

If I manually set the the value of the `v-file-input` into `null`, everything is working fine. How do I retain using `this.$refs.form.reset()` without this error?

```
<v-file-input
  v-model="tableItem.photo"
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg, image/bmp"
  placeholder="Pick an avatar"
  prepend-icon="mdi-camera"
  label="Avatar"
  @change="getImagePreviews()"
></v-file-input>

getImagePreviews() {    
  let reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    this.imageURL = reader.result
  })
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.tableItem.photo)        
},
closeModal() {
  this.tableItem.photo = null // this is working but I need to remove this.$refs.form.reset()
  this.$refs.form.reset()
  this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
}
```

Comment: You have to encapsulate your code in  *** <v-form ref="form">***

[link] (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/forms/#example-validation-with-submit-and-clear)

Comment: Hello sir Pallav! The whole form is already encapsulated in `<v-form ref="form>`, I'm only having error when I include the `v-file-input`. It seems like the `reader.readAsDataURL` is reading an undefinedd value due to `this.$refs.form.reset()`. But I don't know how to work around on this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the readAsDataURL() function accepts only Blob data, you can check if the parameter is of Blob type:

```
getImagePreviews() {    
  if (this.tableItem.photo instanceof Blob){
    this.reader.readAsDataURL(this.tableItem.photo)    
  }else{
    this.imageURL = null
  }
},
```

Also, you may want to initialize the reader in the mounted hook:

```
data: ()=>({
  reader: null
}),
mounted(){
  this.reader = new FileReader();
  this.reader.addEventListener("load", () => {
    this.imageURL = this.reader.result
  })
}
```

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much for this! This syntax `this.tableItem.photo instanceof Blob` + the mounted was ground breaking.